# Different tax on website scope?

Tags: magento-1.9, tax-calculation

**Magento 1.9.x**

I am trying to configure a different VAT rate on website scope. I added a new product tax class `PTC` and a new tax rule `TR`. The new tax rule has my new product tax class `PTC` selected as tax class and the tax rate I selected has 20% VAT configured.

Now when I go to a product in the admin area and switch over to the website scope I want to change the tax rate for, I select my newly added product tax class `PTC`. The result: It calculates no tax, please also see https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vN5M.png.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Thanks!